# Show that if $p$ is prime then $(p-1)!+1$ is not

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

This is an exercise from Beachy and Blair: Abstract algebra:

Show that $7\mid (6!+1)$, $11\mid (10!+1)$ and $19\mid (18!+1)$.

I was thinking let us generalize this to:

Let $p$ be a prime number then we want to show that

$$
p\mid \big((p-1)!+1\big)
$$

So $(p-1)!+1$ is not divisible by numbers up to $p-1$ so it is either divisible by $p$ and or it is a prime itself. So we want to conclude that $(p-1)!+1$ is not a prime if $p$ is. I was thinking about this but I couldn't find a way to tackle the problem. I would be really greatful if someone could give me some HINTS on how to think here (so I can sleep tonight :).

Thank you!

Comment: The claim is false for $p=2$ and for $p=3$ (but $p\mid (p-1)!+1$ still holds for these cases)

Comment: ohh. true. I was so content with the general case that I haven't even looked at small examples. thank you!

Comment: This can be proved using modular arithmetic, but I don't know if you are familiar with that?

Comment: I found the title different from the body!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $1\le k<p$, then there exists a unique $m$ with $1\le m<p$ and $k\cdot m\equiv- 1\pmod p$

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use Wilson's theorem, it's really trivial.

$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$$ for prime $p$, so $p|((p-1)! + 1)$.

Finally note that $(p-1)! + 1$ is strictly greater than $p$ for all $p>3$ to complete the proof of the statement in your title.

If you're not explicitly allowed to use Wilson's theorem, then you can, well, prove it first (proofs are easy to find on the web).

Comment: thanks! let me look at the hint first and if I cannot figure out myself then I will look at your answer. I am allowed to use Wilsons theorem. I am sitting on my couch at home, nobody can stop me :)